# Harmon.ie error when upload file

Tags: harmon.ie

After completing instalation of Harmo.ie for Outlook 2010, I tried to upload file into a custom document Library. For info, the document library used custom content type and has item receiver attached to it (ItemAdded and ItemUpdated). Sometime, harmon.ie display a error which say "Could not upload file... into the selected Library."

After debugging, the error occured before item receivers. Is anybody have information about the issue ? I did'nt find anything in ULS logs and i tried to isolate bug but no luck !!

here the stack trace of harmo.ie :

> !ENTRY com.mainsoft.sharepoint.sidebar.SideBarViewPart 4 0 2015-03-16 14:42:25.892
>   !MESSAGE Impossible de télécharger ...' vers la bibliothèque sélectionnée.
>   Le téléchargement du fichier ...' n'a pas pu être terminé.
>   !STACK 0
>   com.mainsoft.sharepoint.sidebar.services.UploadOperationFailedException: Le téléchargement du fichier'...' n'a pas pu être terminé.
>       at com.mainsoft.sharepoint.sidebar.services.UpdateMetadata.onAfterUpload(UpdateMetadata.java:74)
>       at com.mainsoft.sharepoint.sidebar.services.FilesUploader.uploadNextDocument(FilesUploader.java:169)
>       at com.mainsoft.sharepoint.sidebar.services.FilesUploader.upload(FilesUploader.java:126)
>       at com.mainsoft.sharepoint.sidebar.services.FilesUploader.upload(FilesUploader.java:107)
>       at com.mainsoft.sharepoint.sidebar.operations.BaseFilesUploadOperation.run(BaseFilesUploadOperation.java:157)
>       at com.mainsoft.common.OperationBase.run(OperationBase.java:94)
>       at com.mainsoft.common.OperationBase$1.run(OperationBase.java:33)
>       at com.mainsoft.common.Job$SecondJob.run(Job.java:191)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.threadProc(Thread.java:2297)
>       at java.lang.Thread$1.Invoke(Thread.java:797)
>       at cli.System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Unknown Source)
>       at cli.System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(Unknown Source)
>       at cli.System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please provide your code snippets and error trace

Comment: I could provide code from item receiver but error occured before item receiver code. And I have no error trace, just this error message...

Comment: I added stack trace from Harmo.ie log files

Answer (score 0):

Run Fiddler to trace requests sent from harmon.ie to SharePoint - the trace details may give you some insight. Also try the same operation against a library that doesn't have any event handlers.